# Why HttpsURLConnection returns LocalCloseInputStream when calling getInputStream() on Android 2.2?

Tags: android, https, httpurlconnection

Every second time when i'm creating `HttpsURLConnection` and than calling `getInputStream()` method I'm getting an instance of `LocalCloseInputStream` instead of `ChunkedInputStream`, which immediately returns end when I try to read from this stream. There are not exceptions, just an empty stream.

I've already tried to set keep.alive to false and connection to close. This doesn't work.

There two issues look pretty similar, but unfortunately I haven't found any solution:

http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/d42c95992ae4dbda

http://groups.google.com/group/twitter4j/browse_thread/thread/105342823f7e3c67

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For earlier versions of Android you should be using the Apache HTTP client. It works a lot better.

What you are seeing could be caused by calling `#getInputStream()` more than once - have you checked what the default state for caching is in your app (for cupcake the cache is on by default for HTTP URL connections, i.e. the second time the response may be served from the cache, which is not likely to return a `ChunkedInputStream`).

You can turn caching off by calling [`#setUseCaches(false)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLConnection.html#setUseCaches%28boolean%29) on your connection *before* using it (or disable it for all future connections by calling [`#setDefaultUseCaches(false)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLConnection.html#setDefaultUseCaches%28boolean%29)

Comment: Thanks for reply. I realized that usage of the Apache HTTPClient would be preferable, but I have quite a lot of code already, which I'm actually porting from the a desktop library. So I would try keep using HttpsURLConnection for a while. I use setUseChaches(false) already, it doesn't help.

Comment: Hm. But you are using #getInputStream() twice on the same HttpsURLConnection? Otherwise the HTTP headers received from the server would have to be messed up on the HTTP response (or caching enabled even though you disabled it) as far as I remember from the original HttpsURLConnection in cupcake -> froyo.